# scan hbase table for row where column field value is empty

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I would like to perform a quick filtered scan in the hbase shell to retrieve any records where a specific column value is null or empty. I was told I can do this in PIG as well but don't know how to do that either. Can someone please assist with either method to get this resolved. I will as last option do in java but just thought this would be faster?

```
 **TableName, columnFamily, column**
 test:table     collected:url
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

Tried the following:

```
  scan 'test:table',{ COLUMNS => 'collected:url', LIMIT => 10, FILTER => "ValueFilter( =, 'binaryprefix:<>' )"}
```

No results so maybe it works but does this look correct?

EDIT 2:

Error returned:

```
     hbase(main):008:0> scan 'test:table', {FILTER => 
    SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('collected'), 
    Bytes.toBytes('url'), CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), 
    Bytes.toBytes(''), true, true), COLUMNS => 'collected:url' }
    ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (6 for 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need pig for solving your problem.

In Hbase shell [SingleColumnValueFilter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SingleColumnValueFilter.html) should help you. You need to set `filterIfMissing` to `false`, what is actually the default value. So your scan should look like:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

scan 'YourTable', {FILTER => SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('family'), Bytes.toBytes('field'), CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), Bytes.toBytes('')), COLUMNS => 'family:field' }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. How do import those libraries from the shell command line? do I just submit as it at command prompt? I get the wrong number of arguments error(6 for 4)

Comment: They should be imported by default. Can you send the exact error message which you have?

Comment: In my update I've deleted the last Boolean parameters.  As the default value is used, there is no need to specify them explicitly. But anyway it's curiously that it doesn't work for you. What version of HBase do you have?

Comment: thanks. got it to work. I had to reimport the libraries, drop the boolean parameters and it worked. thanks again.

Comment: @LyashkoKirill do you have any idea why this filter doesn't work and returns records for data == "" (or null) `FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('family', 'has_data', =, 'binary:true', true, true) AND SingleColumnValueFilter('family', 'data', !=, 'binary:')"`. My goal is to retrieve records where has_data == true and data != null/empty

Answer (score 0):

You was close with `ValueFilter`, below command works for me:

```
scan 'item', {LIMIT=>5, COLUMNS => ['data:index'], FILTER => "ValueFilter(=, 'binary:')"}
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.